# Preview for firefox tabs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Windows 7 has really nice features. The preview for opened applications in taskbar:

[image]

Especially if that application has several tabs.

However this feature doesn't support Firefox (or vice-versa: Firefox doesn't support this feature!) and you just see the current active tab in preview and not all opened tabs:

[image: this screenshot]

- Is there any way to make Firefox tabs visible in preview?
- Does Mozilla published any patch/extension/... for this?
- Is there Any Hack/trick/config-changing stuff to make this feature possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Firefox 3.6 beta](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/) at least is required, and it is [not yet perfect](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/11/18/windows-7-taskbar-previews-to-be-disabled-by-default-in-firefox/), but they are working on it (hence why it is not enabled by default yet):

- Type **about:config** in the address bar and filter to **browser.taskbar.previews.enable**
- Change this value to **True**
- Enjoy tab previews!

[image]

Comment: aren't they gone RC with 3.6 already?

Comment: Yes, I was just stating that beta is the minimum requirement. The feature is no better in RC than it is in beta. They plan to refine it with updates to 3.6.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 is released and i'm enjoying the tab-preview of firefox. Thanks John T